# fibrous skeleton of the heart

Tags: cardiology, tissue

is it true to say that "fibrous skeleton is between all of the myocardium and most of the cardiac muscle attach to that"? cause I can't get this that how can it be between all the muscles.
[image]

Comment: Where is this quote from? The phrase "myocardium muscle" is strange usage (muscle is redundant with myocardium).

Comment: edited it. I wrote it wrong sorry